# Is it possible to add animation to Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, animation, ms-access-2013

Is it possible to add animation to Microsoft Access? What I am envisioning is that someone clicks a button on a form and an animation appears and then goes away. Kind of like how when Mario jumps and hits a block, a coin appears and disappears. I know its a very general question, but I couldn't find much online regarding this.

Comment: I'm having a hard time finding this but there was a question not too long ago about creating messages that popup and disappear like some sites on the web use. It linked to a project that used the WinAPI to create the animations (position/fade in/out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move a timer event or similar to adjust the top/left position of a control/picture.

But you wouldn't, as Access (VBA) is single-threaded meaning that while such animation goes on, nothing else will happen, effectively freezing your application. That is really annoying for the user, and that is one of the reasons you meet very little code in this area.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.  You would basically be drawing and redrawing sprites at specific screen coordinates.  It's horrendous in Access, it looks clunky and will kill your app.  The reason you can't find much about it online is because it's a very bad idea to try to incorporate it into a database.

Even if you took a shortcut and had multiple GIFs made up (think of an old-school flip book animation), you still have to draw and redraw a bunch of controls.  I suppose if you *really* wanted it you could add it, but I still think it'll drag and look clunky.

Comment: Yes, agree. Especially if your form has a lot of controls, fickering will be very noticeable, you don't want this. For animation should be used external libraries, which will work in separate processes, it's quite difficult.